# Is there any way to get routing key in listener

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have a Spring Boot application which uses RabbitMQ for async calls.
In listener(consumer), I would like to get routing key from somewhere ?
Is it possible ? Could you please help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is useful tutorial for you: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html

Answer (score 4):

You can get it from MessageProperties.
There is a link to full documentation(find getReceivedRoutingKey method): https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/core/MessageProperties.html

Also a short piece of code:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${spring.rabbitmq.template.queue}")
public void listen(Message message) {
    String receivedRoutingKey = message.getMessageProperties().getReceivedRoutingKey();
    log.info("Routing key: {}", receivedRoutingKey);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Routing Key originally used for message publication is part of the **[Basic.Deliver](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.deliver)** event args in the AMQP 0-9-1 specification.

Without specific example of the code and RabbitMQ clienty library you are using, this is the general answer.  Within your specific RabbitMQ implementation, if you can find a way to access the delivery event args, then it should contain the routing key. If not, I recommend picking another client library which follows the specification more closely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
message.getMessageProperties().getHeader().getReceivedRoutingKey();
```

I have made some mistake in my project therefore I was not able to reach routing key. I found root cause of my problem so the code above solved issue.